# I can print but not scan with my Epson XP-400...what can I do?

Tags: scanner

I can print with no problems with my Epson XP-400 but not scan - which I need to do often for work - there is no support in Linux for Epson xp-400...is there anything I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same printer.

First, go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

type XP-400 in the search field and press enter.

You will need to click Download on each one of these to obtain the following packages

[image]

(If you are using 64 bit, download the **amd64.deb** packages instead of **i386.deb**)

epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_**i386.deb** (full-feature)

epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.0-1lsb3.2_**i386.deb** (generic-driver)

iscan-data_1.28.0-2_all.**deb** (core & data)

iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_**i386.deb** (core & data)

iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_**i386.deb** (network plugin)

Install each of these packages one at a time by right clicking on the .deb files in your downloads folder and selecting open using Ubuntu Software Center.

Because of dependency issues, you must install each of these packages in the same order as in this list or software center will complain.

Also, one of the packages may complain that a newer version is already installed. If you encounter this, skip that package and move on to the next one.

I've tested and verified this using "simple scan", "image scan! for linux", "xsane image scanning program" (with firewall access on port 631), and "acquireimages".

Answer (score 0):

To get the printer and scanner working:

Install Driver and hplip, Setup using hplip and CUPS

In the software manager, download these hplip CUPS xsane and gocr

1. Download and install epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb from:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Type in "XP-400" in the search box (without quotes).

1. Run hplip toolbox and select to run CUPS web interface.
2. Set up printer according to on-screen instructions.
3. Exit both web interface and hplip, reboot.

NOTE: To set up scanner, use XSane. But remember to turn OFF the firewall or it won't work!

To install xsane

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
```

To stop iptables

```
sudo service ufw stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Epson XP-312 printer-scanner and have found that it's possible to scan with the firewall enabled if I add the following ufw rules via the terminal:

```
sudo ufw allow 1865
sudo ufw allow out 1865
```

Though it only works when connected to the printer-scanner with a USB cable.

Hope this helps.